# Locator is not working except id on the Appium for Android in WebView

Tags: java, android, selenium, testing, appium

Trying to do the Testing of Android Application coded in WebView. I have an app that I am trying to automate the Test Cases.

I have a login screen having Email and Password which does have id locaters. That is working fine I am able to locate elements. ITs hybrid app made with ionic. The login button does not have id locater.

So far I have tried this thing.

```
MobileWebBrowserFactory factory;
AndroidDriver<WebElement> appiumdriver;
WebElement LoginElement = appiumdriver.findElement(By.id("username"));
LoginElement.click();
LoginElement.sendKeys("Test");

WebElement PasswordElement = appiumdriver.findElement(By.id("password"));
PasswordElement.click();
PasswordElement.sendKeys("Test");
// Hide Keyboard
appiumdriver.hideKeyboard();
Thread.sleep(2000);

            WebElement LoginButton = appiumdriver
                    .findElementByName("end");
```

it gave me an exception that name is not allowed locator to find all the times. I have used Android and appium drivers both.

Can anyone Suggest to me good libraries for this? I appreciate your help in advance.

Thanks

Comment: Does the Login button has a class name?

Comment: No, It does not. It does have id though

Comment: You are saying login button has id? But your question statement says - The login button does not have id locater.

Comment: Sorry, my bad it does not have an id but it has a name though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done certain changes to the code.

Changed Appium Server to 1.10 to 1.20.2.
Used Android Driver Instance.

Also, Used the Xpath for the non-ionic framework.

It resolved the issue for me and I am able to locate the element using this.

```
        WebElement UsernameElement = appiumdriver.findElementByXPath("//*[@id=\"username\"]/input");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        UsernameElement.click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        UsernameElement.sendKeys("mobile3@20212.com");
```

Maybe the Old Appium was not able to identify the element.

Comment: So, finally you are using `findElementByXPath` instead of `findElementByName` as I suggested...
As about upgrading the Appium Server I do not believe this is the issue.

Comment: findElementByXPath and findElementByName this was I tried already it did not worked. When I reinstalled the Appium that worked only. I downgraded appium just to check and it stops working again. So its appium driver was the issue.

Comment: Ah, Ok. Interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I didn't work with Appium for a long time, so maybe I'm wrong, but as I remember, Appium supports locating elements by `id` or `xpath` only.
So, instead of `findElementByName` try `findElementByXpath`.
The locator should be changed accordingly, so it will be something like

```
WebElement LoginButton = appiumdriver.findElementByXpath("//*[@name='end']");
```

Comment: I tried It it does not work for me. I tried with Androiddriver and Appium driver both.